# Is the complement of the cycle of length $6$ ($C6$) a planar graph?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Is the complement of the cycle of length $6$  ($C6$)  a planar graph?

Comment: Interesting problem statement, but you haven't shown any work or independent thought process. Please see [this article](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/) on MathSE query guidelines.

Comment: The complement of $C_6$ is a graph with $6$ vertices and $9$ edges. Have you tried drawing it?